# SQL Query to select one row where the given data is within the class interval

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table like this:

[image: SQL table]

If I was given a value 32, then I should return the row 2. Similarly, if I was given a value 70, then I should return the row 4. How can I construct a query to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, you can just do

```sql
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE min <= <target> AND max >= <target>
```

If the ranges are meant to be continuous with each other though you don't need to provide both min and max for each row. In which case you could do

```sql
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE min <= <target> ORDER BY min ASC LIMIT 1
```